# Looking at a wallet address, how can I know if it is Ethereum, Litecoin, Bitcoin, etc?

Tags: etherscan

How can I find out what kind of coins a wallet holds based on the wallet's address? For example, if I saw a random wallet address, how can I know whether that wallet is for Ethereum, Bitcoin, Litecoin, or another coin?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the blockchain.

ETH addresses always start with 0x_ _ _ _

**Examples:**

*0x0BC546861FdD94f8EeE54f0570c7f89768074781*

*0x3306b03e847C3b1cA2f6356b53a42dFBA72e127a*

Bitcoin addresses on the other hand have no such edict. They are just a fully random combination of characters.

**Example:** *bc1qar0srrr7xfkvy5l643lydnw9re59gtzzwf5mdq*

Note: Many other Blockchains copy ETH's format, but others like EOS, etc have their own formats that make their addresses recognizable.

There is no specific rule to follow here, but you will quickly catch on as you use them.

Comment: Is there a way you can check with code what type of address it is?

Comment: Well, it is to a degree. You will easily be able to discern between ETH and Bitcoin. But many cryptoAssets have addressed written in a format IDENTICAL to ETH, so there is no way to differentiate between those. (As far as I can think of)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check each blockchain and study what kind of address formats they use.

Comment: Is there a way you can check with code to check what type of address it is?

Comment: Yes,  if you program the logic yourself.

Comment: There's no library that's created that can do it for me?